# Use process.env variables in angular application

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have an Angular application that will have multiple installations (for different customers) and I'd like to use system environment variables to hold things like the URL for the back end service.

I've read lots of questions on here that talk about using config files to hold those settings, but it's not feasible for me to add files to the source code each time a customer wants to install the application.

I know I can bring an environment variable into Grunt (for development purposes) and Express using e.g. process.env.URL, but how do I get that variable into Angular itself?

Comment: a good option could be using browserify but it change all the app logic ^^ may be you could set a constant for the ENV

Comment: I'd like to set a constant if possible - I already have a separate module with various constants and it would be great to bring in a variable from process.env too